# Banach Fixed Point Theorem Proof

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

(Banach Fixed Point Theorem)
Let $X$ be a Banach space, $D$ ⊆ $X$ closed and
$T$: $D$ → $D$ a contraction, which means that $T$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz
constant $L < 1$:
$$||T(u) − T(v)||_X ≤ L||u − v||_X \hspace{1cm}
∀u, v ∈ D.$$
Then, we have:

1. $T$ has a unique fixed-point $\bar{u} ∈ D$.
2. Let $u_0$ ∈ $D$ be arbitrary and $u_{k+1}$ := $T(u_k), \hspace{1cm}$
   $k = 0, 1, . . . ⇒ u_k$ → $u$
3. $||\bar{u} − u_k|| ≤ L||\bar{u} − u_{k−1}||$ $\hspace{1cm}$ $(k ≥ 1)$

$\textbf{To Prove}$,
a) $||\bar{u}-u_k|| \leq \frac {L^k}{1-L}||T(u_0) - u_0||\hspace{1cm} (k ≥ 1)$

b)$||\bar{u}-u_k|| \leq \frac {L}{1-L}||u_k - u_{k-1}||\hspace{1cm} (k ≥ 1)$.

So far I have proved by induction that,
$||u_{k+1} - u_k||≤ L^k||Tu_0 - u_0||$

Now, by considering $m<n$, I proved that,
$||u_n - u_m|| ≤ \frac{L^m}{1-L}||Tu_0-u_0||$ 
So can I prove **a)** by saying let, n= ∞ and m = k?,

also how to I go from here to **b)**

Comment: For $a.)$, use your estimate to show that $(u_n)$ is Cauchy and thus converges to some $\overline{u}$. Then take the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$ of your inequality, then you get the desired inequality.

Comment: For $b.)$ you can telescope. Meaning write $$\Vert \overline{u} - u_k \Vert = \Vert \overline{u} - u_N + \sum_{j=1}^{N-k} (u_{k+j}-u_{k+j-1}  )\Vert$$ and then convert this into a geometric series by taking the limit $N\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: For b),  I solved up to, ||u - uk|| ≤ L  ∑ ||(u(k+j-1) - u(k+j-2)||. I can't figure out how to make it ||uk - uk-1||/(1-L). Sorry but I don't know how to write equation in comments

Comment: You can use $$\Vert u_{k+j} - u_{k+j-1} \Vert \leq L^j \Vert u_k - u_{k-1} \Vert.$$ Hope this helps.